# Linking the Version Number for multiple Configurations in Teamcity

Tags: git, teamcity

I have TeamCity set up with 2 configurations for my application.  The two versions are Release and Beta.  Each of those configurations is set to build when a new commit occurs in either the 'Beta' branch or the 'master' branch in our Git source control.  Right now the version numbers are set independently.  Ideally what I would like to do is keep the Release version incrementing like it is (1.2.x.0, 1.2.x+1.0....), but have the beta branch version number be dependent on the preceding release version # i.e. if the release version is 1.2.x.0 then the beta releases would be 1.2.x.1, 1.2.x.2..... and then reset when a new Release is built.  Does anyone know how I can set this up?  I am currently using TeamCity 8.1.1 and will probably update to 8.1.2 in the next week or two.